# can we change train x , train y arrays to image.DirectoryIterator object in tensorflow?

Tags: keras, tensorflow

i have used ImageDataGenerator in tensorflow to read images which is an object later i changed them to arrays train x , train y to do some preprocessing now i want to change them back to image.DirectoryIterator object to feed them in to pretrained model is there any way to do so?

Comment: In this way, you will get an ugly workaround. Please try to explain, what are you trying to achieve in this preprocessing? There must be an elegant and simple solution to your task if look holistically.

Comment: sry... i wanted to do finger print enhancement and there is a python library "fingerprint_enhancer" which does not taking  image.DirectoryIterator object as prameter so i splitted x values and y values from the object and passed x vlaues of a images to the fingerprint_enhancer function.